# Amazon AWS Athena S3 and Glacier Mixed Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, amazon-athena

## Amazon Athena Log Analysis Services with S3 Glacier

We have petabytes of data in S3.  We are https://www.pubnub.com/ and we store usage data in S3 of our network for billing purposes.  We have tab delimited log files stored in an S3 bucket.  Athena is giving us a **`HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR`** failure.

Our S3 bucket is setup to automatically push to AWS Glacier after 6 months.  Our bucket has S3 files hot and ready to read in addition to the Glacier backup files.  We are getting access errors from Athena because of this.  The file referenced in the error is a Glacier backup.

My guess is the answer will be: don't keep glacier backups in the same bucket.  We don't have this option with ease due to our data volume sizes.  I believe Athena will not work in this setup and we will not be able to use Athena for our log analysis.

However if there is a way we can use Athena, we would be thrilled.  Is there a solution to **`HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR`** and a way to skip Glacier files?  Our s3 bucket is a flat bucket **without folders**.

[image: AWS Athena S3 Operation Exception]

The S3 file object name shown in the above and below screenshots is omitted from the screenshot.  The file reference in the `HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR` is in fact the Glacier object.  You can see it in this screenshot of our S3 Bucket.

[image: Amazon S3 Bucket object in Glacier accessed by Athena]

Note I tried to post on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ but that was no bueno.

[image]

Comment: I think this might be a bug in Athena. Nowhere in the Athena documentation they mention Glacier.

Comment: I added some more details showing our s3 object filename is in fact in the glacier object state.

Comment: You can use Glacier Select with SQL https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/glacier-select.html

Comment: even glacier restore doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [the release of February 18, 2019](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2019-02-18.html) Athena will ignore objects with the GLACIER storage class instead of failing the query:

> […] As a result of fixing this issue, Athena ignores objects transitioned to the GLACIER storage class. Athena does not support querying data from the GLACIER storage class.

Comment: You can use Glacier Select with SQL https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/glacier-select.html

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-ug.pdf) dated May 16 2017 states specifically that Athena does not support the GLACIER storage class:

> Athena does not support different storage classes within the bucket specified by the LOCATION
>   clause, does not support the GLACIER storage class, and does not support Requester Pays
>   buckets. For more information, see [Storage Classes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html), [Changing the Storage Class of an Object in
>   |S3|](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ChgStoClsOfObj.html), and [Requester Pays Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html) in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.

We are also interested in this; if you get it to work, please let us know how. :-)

Comment: Thank you!  This makes sense.  BTW we've become Athena User-experts.  Presto is great.

Comment: @StephenBlum Did presto solve this problem for you?  If so, how?  We are facing the same issue.

Comment: @killdash9 we instead created a new bucket, with `/Year/Month/Day/Hour/` partitions. This solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You must have an S3 bucket to work with. In addition, the AWS account that you use to initiate a S3 Glacier Select job must have write permissions for the S3 bucket. The Amazon S3 bucket must be in the same AWS Region as the vault that contains the archive object that is being queried.

S3 glacier select runs the query and stores in S3 bucket

Bottom line, you must move the data into an S3 buck to use teh S3 glacier select statement.  Then use Athena on the 'new' S3 bucket.