# Why athena doesn’t read from glacier (s3) storage?

Tags: amazon-athena

I created external table on underlying data s3. And pointed table1 to s3 standard storage and table2 to glacier storage. Table1 is reading data but not table2.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon AWS Athena S3 and Glacier Mixed Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862941/amazon-aws-athena-s3-and-glacier-mixed-bucket)

Answer (score 0):

S3 objects in the Glacier storage class are not accessible in the same way as normal objects, they need to be retrieved from Glacier before they can be read – which requires a special API call, and also costs money.

Athena is reading objects from S3 just like you would with the S3 API, which means reading objects with the Glacier storage class doesn't work.

It would also not make any sense for Athena to even try reading Glacier objects since the retrieval time is longer than the maximum query duration for an Athena query.

---

Update: in [the release notes for February 18, 2019](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/release-note-2019-02-18.html) it says that Athena now ignores objects transitioned to Glacier, rather than failing the query. The change was likely in effect earlier since releases are often made in different regions at different times and release notes only get updated once it's fully deployed.